# Magento 2.1 Admin login issue - Someone logged into this account from another device session is terminated

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento 2 admin login issue when trying to do multiple admin login from different PC or location, its automatically logout from the PC where trying to do second login with same admin user in different pc - it gives Following error

> Someone logged into this account from another device or browser. Your current session is terminated.

Comment: Refer http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-admin-login-into-same-account.html may be help you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> **Solution**: Because of security purpose Magento by default disable the admin login share session and therefor while in development mode you need to enable this from:
>
> Admin >> "Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security" and change value of "Admin Account Sharing" to "Yes".

Check attached screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. 
This seems to be an addition in the 2.1.x line, didn't have that problem before. 
I wish Magento would stop annoying with such new "Features"

Comment: XML Path `admin/security/admin_account_sharing`, just for the record.

Comment: Same as frontend, how to handle it