# Magento 2.2 keep logging out

Tags: admin, login, session, admin-panel, logout

My magento installation is keep logging out when login with admin account.

Sometimes 3 mins, some times 10 mins.

After log in, it shows:

> **All other open sessions for this account were terminated.**

I guess that means the sessions is still valid but browser does not save it?

So I changed several computers and browsers, all tries got the same issue.

As I remember, it didn't happen back to **2.1**.

After upgrade, it keep happening.

And admin username/password is not able to save in the browser as well.

Do there's any new config in 2.2?

I've edited the back end session time and php setting, not work either.

Comment: If some one will logged in from another computer with same admin details then you will be automatically logged out from admin panel. 
Please check with that if any other person is using same admin details ?

Comment: Check this answer it will help you for sure. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126583/49821

Comment: @Magento2Learner no, I login with my own computer only.
and seems it is solved after I turned cron jobs off.

Answer (score 3):

> To disable this feature go to "Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security" and change value of "Admin Account Sharing" to "Yes".
>
> I hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the Admin session Lifetime at

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime

Comment: I've done this before :)
And php.ini, but still has the same issue.