# Can two people log in at the same time in Admin?

Tags: magento2, login

Can two or more people log in to a Magento e-commerce site at the same time? Can one person process sales while another updates products?

Comment: please specify magento version ? 
and you want to user same user login at two place ?

Comment: Magento2 - previously we could but since upgrade to Magento 2 the first user gets bumped off when second user signs in. Same user login, two different computers.

Comment: @AlexMcGregor you should check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/126583/20064)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2.1 Admin login issue - Someone logged into this account from another device session is terminated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126582/magento-2-1-admin-login-issue-someone-logged-into-this-account-from-another-de)

Answer (score 1):

You need to **enabled Admin Account Sharing option** from admin to allowed logged in same user simultaneously.

> **Go to  Admin >> "Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security"**
>   **and change value of "Admin Account Sharing" to "Yes".**

Second thing - Yes that is also possible one person do sales operations and another will do updates products with same user.

**Note :** **But still as a part of Security Create new user for sales with limited access by using ACL functionality of magento 2 and give access to sales related operations to sales user same way for others.**

Comment: @AlexMcGregor - If you found answer as helpful , then accept as solution so other user gets helped , Happy to help and keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

**The above answers are correct. You can do it by using CLI also:**

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/admin_account_sharing 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this feature go to

```
Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security
```

and

change value of ***Admin Account Sharing*** to ***Yes***.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple admins can login with the same account in admin. But you will need change settings in admin.

```
Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security
```

Change value of Admin Account Sharing to Yes.